# How to vectorise outer-products

Tags: python, vectorization

I have two matrices P1 and P2 of the same size. I am taking their rows P1[j] and P2[j] and forming matrices via an outerproduct using numpy. In a python loop format this is achieved by forming the list of matrices A

```
for j in range(0,np.shape(P1)[0]):
    A[j] = np.outer(P1[j],P2[j])
```

I would like to vectorise this operation.

Comment: It's not clear what you are after you set `A[i]` to equal  `P1[j],P2[j])` over and over again in the inner loop. In the end every row of `A` is the same — the result of `outer` for the last value of `j`.

Comment: I see what you mean, I have changed it. I am just computing j=1,...,n outer products where n is the number of rows in P1 and P2 and storing them in A.

Comment: It might be possible using `np.einsum` in combination with `np.newaxis` but I can't figure out the syntax at the moment.

Comment: For 1D arrays the outer product is `np.einsum('i,j->ij', a, b)`

Comment: Hi Joe, I am aware of the outer product as given by einsum, but I am not aware of how to incorporate newaxis into the problem

Answer (score 0):

`np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk',P1,P2)` gave me exactly the thing I wanted.